# Azure mobile client 4.0 - how use LoginAsync?

Tags: azure, xamarin, mobile, xamarin.android, azure-mobile-services

I used azure mobile net client 3.1.0.0. This is my old code in my Android client:

```
 IMobileServiceClient client;
 //for Android
 //from Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Mobile.Ext
 var user = await client.LoginAsync(Forms.Context, provider);
```

Now I have updated to the new version 4.0. I need authorization with Google account. This is the code I found in the documentation:

```
 IMobileServiceClient client;
 var token = new JObject {{"access_token", "access_token_value"}};
 user = await client.LoginAsync(provider, token);
```

How do I get "access_token_value" on client Android?
Please help me. I need a small example or reference to the documentation.

Comment: what 'flow' have you been using? the server flow (where a browser window appears and your server directly gets the access token and returns it to you) or the client flow (where the facebook app might open and you get the token locally and send it to your server? (if that hasn't existed in the old azure sdk - which would you like to use?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved this issue. 
1.It was necessary to use this class:

```
Microsoft.WindowsAzure.MobileServices.MobileServiceClient client;
var user = await client.LoginAsync(Forms.Context, provider, "{url_scheme_of_your_app}");
```

2.It is necessary to add this to AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<activity android:name="com.microsoft.windowsazure.mobileservices.authentication.RedirectUrlActivity"
      android:launchMode="singleTop" android:noHistory="true">
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
    <data android:scheme="{url_scheme_of_your_app}" android:host="easyauth.callback" />
</intent-filter>
```

"url_scheme_of_your_app" - text identifier. Ex - "app911";

3. Add your app to the [Allowed External Redirect URLs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-mobile/app-service-mobile-android-get-started-users#a-nameredirecturlaadd-your-app-to-the-allowed-external-redirect-urls)

   Ex. url app911://easyauth.callback

This is [example](https://github.com/dhei/azure-mobile-apps-xamarinforms-login-sample).

Answer (score 1):

According to your description, I created my Xamarin.Android application to test this issue. For Microsoft.Azure.Mobile.Client 4.0.0, I found my project would reference the sdk under the following path:

`Microsoft.Azure.Mobile.Client.4.0.0\lib\netstandard1.4\Microsoft.Azure.Mobile.Client.dll`

And I would encounter the same issue as you mentioned. Then I tried to downgrade to [Microsoft.Azure.Mobile.Client 4.0.0-alpha-001](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Azure.Mobile.Client/4.0.0-alpha-001), and I could find the expected extension methods for `LoginAsync`. At this time, the sdk would under the following path:

`Microsoft.Azure.Mobile.Client.4.0.0-alpha-001\lib\monoandroid44\Microsoft.Azure.Mobile.Client.dll`

Also, for Azure Mobile Client SDK 3.1.0, the reference path looks like this:

`Microsoft.Azure.Mobile.Client.3.1.0\lib\monoandroid\Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Mobile.Ext.dll`

After some trials, I found the following sdk supports the extension method for `LoginAsync` as follows:

`C:\Bruce\Thread Handling Projects\Bruce.AndroidApp\packages\Microsoft.Azure.Mobile.Client.4.0.0\lib\monoandroid71`
[image]

> How do I get "access_token_value" on client Android? Please help me. I need a small example or reference to the documentation.

From your old code, I assumed that you are using server-flow authentication, for using server-flow via Microsoft.Azure.Mobile.Client 4.0.0 which supports `MonoAndroid >= 7.1`, I assumed that you need to upgrade your android version for your xamarin.android project. Or you need to downgrade to the version before 4.0.0. Additionally, you could refer to [client-managed flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-mobile/app-service-mobile-dotnet-how-to-use-client-library#clientflow) and [server-managed flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-mobile/app-service-mobile-dotnet-how-to-use-client-library#serverflow).

**UPDATE:**

After change android version to 7.1, then I could use Microsoft.Azure.Mobile.Client 4.0.0 as follows:

[image]
[image]

For upgrading to android 7.1, you could refer to [here](https://blog.xamarin.com/android-7-1-developer-preview-now-available/).

Comment: I have updated my answer for test, you could refer to it.